# Why this class variable is None even though it has been initialized?

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning Kivy, and the purpose if this piece of code is to cache a widget, but I am having trouble understanding what is going on with it:

```
class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    current_weather = ObjectProperty()

    def show_current_weather(self, location=None):
        self.clear_widgets()

        print(WeatherRoot.current_weather)
        print(self.current_weather)

        if location is None and self.current_weather is None:
            location = 'New York (US)'

        if location is not None:
            self.current_weather = Factory.CurrentWeather()
            self.current_weather.location = location
        self.add_widget(self.current_weather)
```

The problem is that `current_weather`, as far as I know this is a class variable, is defined to be an `ObjectProperty`, and since I do not have an instance variable (I think so) that overrides this variable, when I refer `self.current_weather` I am referring to the class variable, so I think that `self.current_weather` is the same as `WeatherRoot.current_weather`, but is is not since when I printed those variables I expected to have both to be an `ObjectProperty` instance, and I got:

```
<ObjectProperty name=current_weather>
None
```

*My point is that this variable would never be `None` because it is a class variable so it is always an `ObjectProperty`, but it seems it is possible to be `None`, and I do not understand why.*

This is the GUI of this application:

[image]

[image]

This is my Kivy file:

```
WeatherRoot:
<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm

<LocationButton>:
    on_press: app.root.show_current_weather(self.text)

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    search_input: search_box
    search_results: search_results_list
    BoxLayout:
        height: '40dp'
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: 'Search'
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: 'Current Search'
            size_hint_x: 25
    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.LocationButton)
    Button:
        height: '40dp'
        size_hint_y: None
        text: 'Cancel'
        on_press: app.root.show_current_weather(None)
```

So, when I press the cancel button and no location was previously searched, the default value is hardcoded as it can be seen to `'New York (US)`. When I have searched for a location previously and I press the cancel button, this location is displayed.

Could somebody please explain me what is going on with this variable `current_weather`? I thought that this class variable was not needed, but when I deleted it my app crashed.

In case you need, this is the whole code I have:

```
import json

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.factory import Factory

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    current_weather = ObjectProperty()

    def show_current_weather(self, location=None):
        self.clear_widgets()

        print(WeatherRoot.current_weather)
        print(self.current_weather)

        if location is None and self.current_weather is None:
            location = 'New York (US)'

        if location is not None:
            self.current_weather = Factory.CurrentWeather()
            self.current_weather.location = location
        self.add_widget(self.current_weather)

    def show_add_location_form(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(AddLocationForm())


class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()

    def search_location(self):
        search_template = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/' \
                          'data/2.5/find?q={}&type=like&APPID=' \
                          '090428d02304be901047796d430986e3'
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        print(search_url)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        cities = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'], d['sys']['country'])
                  for d in data['list']]
        # self.search_results.item_strings = cities
        self.search_results.adapter.data.clear()
        self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(cities)
        self.search_results._trigger_reset_populate()


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass


WeatherApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html). Although defined at class level, they have instance-level behaviour, and to a first approximation will behave like an instance variable.

Comment: when you say that __Properties are descriptors__, you are stating that Kivy properties are defined as descriptors? Or you mean that they are Python properties, i.e., a method that can be access as if it were an attribute?

Comment: Kivy properties are descriptors in the sense that they implement the descriptor protocol as in the linked documentation. They're similar to normal python properties in how they behave, but their implementation is different (and they include extra behaviour).